# Вставка множества строк на основе подзапроса

Tags: mysql, sql

Нужно вставить в таблицу `master_services` ВСЕ id из таблицы `services`, а `id_master` сделать везде '40'

```
INSERT INTO master_services (id_master, id_services) VALUES ('40',(SELECT id FROM services));
```

> 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: `SELECT id FROM services` — вы забыли `WHERE`, вот подзапрос и возвращает всю таблицу для вставки в одно поле.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Там, где вы поставили подзапрос, ожидается *одно голое значение* для значения *одной вставляемой строки*.

Результаты подзапросов из одной строки и одного столбца СУБД неявно "разворачивает" в голое значение, но когда значений несколько... сами видите.

Вставка через`VALUES` даёт возможность описать явно каждую вставляемую строчку прямо в запросе. Это не ваш случай, вам нужно собрать по строчке на каждую выбираемую из другой таблицы, вы не знаете заранее, сколько их будет. Так что строки вам нужно описывать не через  `VALUES`, а через `SELECT`.

И не забывайте, что в `SELECT` могут быть и выражения. В том числе константы, никак не зависящие от выбираемой строки.

```
INSERT
  INTO master_services (
    id_master,
    id_services
  )
  SELECT
    '40' AS id_master, -- в алиасах необходимости может и нет,
    id AS id_services  -- но с ними понятнее, что происходит
    FROM services
```

См. [документацию MySQL по `INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: ааа блин круто) работает) спс